# Pipe and STDOUT

Tags: c, pipe, fork

I am learning how to use fork and pipes and I have problems with this code:

```
int pid;
char *command_arg[] = {"date", NULL, NULL};

pid = fork();

if (pid == 0)
{
  execvp("date", command_arg);
}
else
{
  wait(NULL);
}
```

With execvp I want to run the command "date" and write the output to stdout. Do I need here a pipe for writing "date" to STDOUT? How do I do this in this example?

Comment: Have to tried this out?

Comment: Are you aware that file descriptors for stdin/stdout/stderr are inherited by the child?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the fork() man page:

> ```
>    *  The child inherits copies of the parent's set of open file  descrip‐
>       tors.   Each  file  descriptor  in the child refers to the same open
>       file description (see open(2)) as the corresponding file  descriptor
>       in  the parent.  This means that the two descriptors share open file
>       status flags, current file offset, and signal-driven I/O  attributes
>       (see the description of F_SETOWN and F_SETSIG in fcntl(2)).
> ```

In other words, you don't have to do anything special to get `date`'s output to the parent's stdout.